# JSON as a form parameter

Tags: java, json, extjs

I am having issue with sending JSON as form parameter. I have the following code :

```
 form = Ext.DomHelper.append(document.body, {
                                action: '/exportExcel',
                                cn: [
                                        {
                                            tag:'input',
                                            name : 'columnsToTitles',
                                            value : Ext.JSON.encode(exportConfig[1])                                                
                                        },
                                        {
                                            tag:'input',
                                            name : 'reportName',
                                            value : 'Final Reports'
                                        }
                                ],
                                method: 'exportWorkItems' || 'GET',
                                tag: 'form',
                                target: frameId
                            });
 form.submit();
 form.onload = null;                                   
 form.parentNode.removeChild(form);
```

Ext.JSON.encode(exportConfig[1]) evaluates to the following JSON string

```
"{"title":"Title","seqTask":"SeqTask","platform":"Platform"}"
```

After the form submits, Spring MVC controller method receives only "{" as the 'columnsToTitles' request parameter.
I have used similar encoding technique before and it worked. Not sure why am I just receiving a "{" as the parameter. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you check the network tab to make sure the entire JSON string is being sent? Why don't you try submitting a regular form without Ext? Put JSON into one of the fields and make sure you can submit a form with JSON in one of its fields. Also, post the code you are using to access the data sent over the wire.

Comment: I have checked the network tab, its not sending the correct data. I found the following in "Query String Parameters":: columnsToTitles:{ and
reportName:WI Reports

Comment: I am not using a regular form because the target of the form is a hidden iframe for file download.

Comment: It seems to be something with `Ext.DomHelper` it's probably having a hard time setting the value to something containing quotes. See https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5a8 for a reproduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `DOMHelper` is not properly escaping the quotes in your JSON string. It's creating an input field that looks like

```
<input name="columnsToTitles" value="{"title":"Title","seqTask":"SeqTask","platform":"Platform"}">
```

This *feature* is clearly noted in the documentation

> NOTE: For other arbitrary attributes, the value will currently not be
>   automatically HTML-escaped prior to building the element's HTML
>   string. This means that if your attribute value contains special
>   characters that would not normally be allowed in a double-quoted
>   attribute value, you must manually HTML-encode it beforehand (see
>   Ext.String.htmlEncode) or risk malformed HTML being created. This
>   behavior may change in a future release.

Therefore, you can just escape your value

```
 form = Ext.DomHelper.append(document.body, {
     action: '/exportExcel',
     cn: [{
        tag:'input',
        name : 'columnsToTitles',
        value : Ext.String.htmlEncode(Ext.JSON.encode(exportConfig[1]))
     },
```

Then your input tag will look like

```
<input name="columnsToTitles" value="{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Title&quot;,&quot;seqTask&quot;:&quot;SeqTask&quot;,&quot;platform&quot;:&quot;Platform&quot;}">
```

Answer (score 0):

`form.submit()` operation cannot send `JSON` format properly. 
You can use `Ext.Ajax.Request`. I think this is a better approach. 
An example is in [here](http://www.sivalabs.in/2011/06/how-to-post-and-get-json-between-extjs.html).

Comment: Please point to something that says you can't send JSON in a submit. If I have a textfield and I type JSON into it, won't it send it without a problem? I think it's more likely that it's a problem with encoding on the server.

Comment: Its for a file download, so Ajax wouldn't work. Earlier I have used hidden form with input fields to hold parameters and then submitted the request. It worked with Ext.util.JSON.encode (ExtJS 3). I am using ExtJS 4 which only has Ext.JSON.encode method and its not working. Another difference is in ExtJS 3, I was using HTML to create form whereas with ExtJS4 I am using Ext.DomHelper.append

Comment: @JuanMendes Can you please shed a little more light on encoding on the server?

Comment: @JuanMendes I don't know the exact reason. But standard ExtJS form object does not convert JSON object as to be sent. The following blog post (#7) also said same think from Sencha.                             `When a form is submitted, it is not submitted in JSON format.
In order to submit JSON string, Ext.Ajax.request must be used.` http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?132082-jsonData-in-submit-action-of-form

Comment: @CahitGungor As you said Ext.Ajax.Request works fine but the form doesnt work. Can you give an example for BASE64 encoded JSON string?

Comment: @CahitGungor That post is saying that the entire form is not sent as JSON, it's sent as standard key-value pairs. That doesn't prevent one of the key value pairs from being JSON, does it?

Comment: ExtJS library do not include Base64 util. An example javascript is here (http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?35328-Ext.util.base64-(encode-decode)). @JuanMendes 's answer using `Ext.String.htmlEncode` is better than BASE64 encode-decode, since you have to handle encoded string on server side. About single JSON parameter issue; @JuanMendes said, if you were getting that value from a text box, it should not be a problem. On the other hand if you set it explicitly in your code, special characters keep un-escaped.

Comment: Though there's a comment that explains that Cahit did understand the problem, the answer as is does not have a good suggestion and misunderstands the problem. If you update it, I'll remove the downvote.